# Way to force User to Enter Password in MVC to perform certain Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a CRUD model in a MVC project. However I am trying to make a User enter his password even if the User is Authenticated when performing certain Actions.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete_MV(mainvehicle c, int id = 0)
{
//verify user password
//provide backup/download link for userdata and delete data on server
}
```

Comment: Just add the `password` field to your view model and validate it in your action (or set is as required in your viewmodel).

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom action filter for this?

Comment: @Mike I am currently trying to do the same. But I am sure ther is a simpler way in MVC. I remember doing sth similar in Aspx just trying to retrace memory :)

Comment: You can make a global one that checks just for the names of the actions (vs putting the attribute on every action method that needs it). I know you can add stuff to the web.config to force security but I ahven't seen anything in ol' aspx that handles actions. You probably could also have a custom route and custom route handler that redirects takes care of this.

Comment: Are your users part of a active directory domain?

Comment: @KeesdeWit I am not part of active directory domain.